# Running Code server on subdomain with nginx reverse-proxy

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, reverse-proxy

I have a flask web server running on an ubuntu server on port 8000, with an nginx reverse proxy to port 80. I also want to run a code-server from [code.com](https://coder.com) on a subdomain (code.example.com) at the same time. I set up code server to run on port 8443, and I have a reverse proxy configured the way they specify on their github page, but whenever I go to code.example.com, I am redirected to localhost:8443. This is my nginx site config (/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.com):

```
server {
server_name www.example.com example.com;

location / {

include uwsgi_params;
uwsgi_pass unix:/home/ubuntu/server/server.sock;
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/;

}


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot




}
server {
    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot



listen 80;
server_name www.example.com example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot




}

server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name code.example.com;
    location / {
       proxy_pass http://localhost:8443/;
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Connection upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding gzip;
    }
 }
```

I have not found a solution that works, I have even tried this adding before proxy_pass

```
   proxy_redirect off;
   proxy_set_header Host code.example.com;
```

To handle any redirects inside code-server, but it should be able to be hosted on a domain name, even a subdomain. I appreciate any help, so please respond if you have an idea! Thank you.

NOTE: Please tell me if this is not the correct site to post this question, and I will move it, I put it here because I saw other reverse proxy nginx questions.

Comment: Use private browser mode (Ctrl+Shift+P typically), otherwise the old 301 that you already eradicated may be still applied by your browser's cache.

Comment: Thanks @kubanczyk, but now code.example.com just displays my flask app, but it does not redirect.

Comment: Is it 8442 or 8443? You seem to have used them interchangeably. Pick one and use it everywhere.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I have changed my question to use 8443 everywhere, but I still get the error, cannot find the server code.example.com

Comment: You have to put that in the DNS (or at least in `/etc/hosts`).

Comment: I have proper DNS for my Ip through Google Domains, and I have code.example.com in my /etc/hosts file, and I am seeing my flask app again. Did I do my /etc/hosts config right? I can upload it if needed.

Comment: Your config looks fine, but is nginx actually running it?

Comment: Nginx is properly proxying my flask app, so it should be. Is there any way to check?

Comment: There is a way to check - `nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf -t`. The `-c <path>` is for config file location, and `-t` tests the config for errors. I've used nginx to proxy pass to two different domains on the same machine several times; I can't determine what's wrong with your config, but I can upload a working config as an answer.

Comment: I tried again and it worked properly, but when I try to add https using the cert.pem and privkey.pem from a certbot --nginx. But now I cannot access the page because the server automatically redirects me multiple times, and the request times out.

Answer (score 0):

I can't determine why your config isn't working, but I can provide you with a template I've used to do the same thing. Be sure to replace the path to your SSL certificates as needed.

I've used Certbot with this config, and it works well, even with a single certificate for multiple domains.

```
# ... 
http {
  server {
    listen  80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
  }

  server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    listen       [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name  example.com;
    # relevant ssl settings here...

    location / {
      proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8000;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }

  ssl_certificate <path_to_certbot_fullchain.pem> # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate_key <path_to_certbot_privkey.pem> # managed by Certbot
  }

  server {
    listen  80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name sub.example.com;
    return 301 https://sub.example.com$request_uri;
  }

  server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    listen       [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name  sub.example.com;
    # relevant ssl settings here...

    location / {
      proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8443;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
  }

  ssl_certificate <path_to_certbot_fullchain.pem> # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate_key <path_to_certbot_privkey.pem> # managed by Certbot
}
# ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, I have gotten it to work, but only on http, when I run code server with https using the nginx ssl certificates from certbot, I get redirected multiple times back and forth before my browser times out.

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure why that would be. I'm assuming you added a redirect for the subdomain from http to https?

Comment: Yes I did use a redirect from when I ran certbot, but when I remove it, I get a 502 bad gateway.

Comment: Hm I’m not sure what to make of it. Would you want to try the config I sent as a test? See if it’s maybe something else in the system? (I just know that this config works well)

Comment: I solved the redirect issue by changing the proxy to https://localhost:8443 because code server only allows https connections.